# PHP & MySQLi php_network_getaddresses error

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to my database and I am getting the following error: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.`

I am using `Mamp Pro 4.5.0` this is my current setup.

```
public function Connect() {
    $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database) or $this->error(mysqli_connect_error());

    $this->connected = true;
}
```

I can post a fuller version of my config file and mysql class file if needed.

Comment: check that `$this->hostname` is what it would be 'localhost' usually

Comment: It is and I do not understand what the issue is.

$config['MySQL']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['MySQL']['username'] = 'alex';
$config['MySQL']['password'] = '******';
$config['MySQL']['database'] = 'asset';

Comment: check inside the function we dont see where `$config['MySQL']['hostname']` becomes  `$this->hostname`

Comment: print here, what inside $this->hostname

Comment: i think we need to see full implementation, is $config a variable on the same class of the function?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! So my error was that I was calling calling $config['MySQL'][''] with $core->config['MySQL']['']. It was how I was calling it when I was coding on older versions of PHP and I had everything listed in classes. Thank you all for the help.